# When I focus on ionic input and textarea it's goes to above the viewport in ipad when keyboard open

Tags: cordova, ipad, scroll, ionic-framework, viewport

When I focused on ionic input or textarea it's goes to above the viewport in ipad if keyboard open

Answer (score 0):

If your screen doesn't need to scroll, then a work around for this is to use the [ionic keyboard plugin](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard) to disable scroll.

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
```